# How to load from collection into a template before anything else as if it were hardcoded?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to load a url from my database collection into an `<img src="*url*" >` tag.

For now I simply publish/subscribe my collection and then retrive the url out of the collection and put it into the template like this:

```js
...
Template.navigation.helpers({
logoUrl: function(){
   return Img.findOne().url;
}
})
...
<template name="navigation">
<img src="{{logoUrl}}"  alt="logo" >
...
```

The problem is, the url is loaded after everything else is loaded. That leads to the issue that for the time of pageload that image is not showing up. In case of the Logo, that is very ugly. So I want it to be there as if the url were hardcoded in the img tag.

How would I do that with Meteor?

e.g. in a PHP file i would simply say:

```php
<?php $url = 'www.blabla.com/myurlwhatever' ?>

<img src="<?=$url ?>" >
```

Of course that would not be reactive, and the url would not change without reloading the whole page, but it would at least show the image instantly after the tag is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a concept misunderstanding here. PHP is rendered on the server. Therefore the image is directly there as soon as the page content is loaded because the whole page is prerendered. In my case above, everything was rendered on the client, which is the regular way.

So to achieve the desired result, one has to take a look at server side rendering (SSR) for Meteor. This is a huge topic and I am not sure if SSR is possible with Blaze.

A simple workaround to avoid ugly artifacts during loading, is to hide everything behind a loading screen, or at least the artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your subscription to the collection is ready before the template gets rendered?

You might want to wait for your subscription to be ready and wrap your HTML in the following helper.

```
{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady }}
    ... html code goes in between the tags ...
{{/else}}
    ... show something else, for example a spinner
{{/if}}
```

And subscribe on the template.

```
Template.yourtemplatename.onCreated( function() {
  this.autorun(() => {
    this.subscribe('yourcollection');
  });
});
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. It seems like there is a difference between subscriptionsReady and collection data is actually loaded. Because the subscription ready is fired instanly, but the collection has no data, so the url appears as before after a short timeperiod...  btw {{/else}} should be {{else}}.

Comment: Oh I missed the subscribe on the template, will try it now.

Comment: Well but no, that makes no sense. I am getting a spinner for the img now, as long as the url is not loaded. But I would like to have the Url to be there as soon as the body tag is loaded and the user starts to see the page. Of course one could hide the whole page behind a huge spinner until everything is loaded, but that is not wanted for now.

Comment: Kadira made a fast tender package that you might have to checkout then: https://github.com/kadirahq/fast-render

Comment: @henk BTW, hiding the page waiting for the data to arrive is what you would have gotten using PHP. With Meteor, your client already knows how to render the page structure, that is why you have a template rendering immediately, but it has to wait for data to arrive from the server to populate your img src since it comes from a collection. Fastrender helps for the first page only. If your logoUrl is used throughout your site, you could use a global subscription.

Answer (score 1):

As you figured out, your template renders before your subscriptions are "ready", i.e. before they have received their data from the server.

The usual workaround with Blaze is to display your template (or its content) conditionally, checking whether your data is ready or not.

For example, you could simply do:

```spacebars
{{#if logoUrl}}
  <img src="{{logoUrl}}"  alt="logo" >
{{/if}}
```

As long as your subscription is not ready yet, `logoUrl` is `undefined`, and the `#if` block condition is not met.

Once your subscription gets ready, the `logoUrl` helper re-runs (if it finds data in your `Img` collection). Provided you now have some data, the `#if` block condition is now met, and your `<img>` tag is displayed, with its `src` attribute filled in.

Comment: Sadly that does not solve the main problem. As long as the collection is empty on the client. The url is missing, and the logo is missing. But I want it to be there on the fly. As if I would hardcode the url in the img tag. 

Is it possible to get the url out of the collection on the server and push it into the html before the html is served to the client, like one would do with php?

Comment: You have to look for `fastrender` package for that. But you would probably have to make sure your project fits what this package needs, I think mainly using Iron:router or Flow:router